# React Router : Router one component exact other non exact

Tags: reactjs, react-router

this my app component with all the routes

```
 render() {

    return (    

    < BrowserRouter >

      <div className="App">                 

         <FuncFact />           

         <Route exact path="/" component = {Anime} />

         <Route  exact path="/Controls"  component= {Controls} />

         <Route exact path="/Profile" component= {Profile} />

         <Route exact path="/People"   component = {People} />

         <Route exact path="/Inbox"   component = {ChatApp} />


       </div>

    </ BrowserRouter >

    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

all of these components are rendered as 'single & only' component but **i want to render also inbox component alongside others** not as exact how to do it

Comment: Just remove the prop `exact`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to render the `<ChatApp>` component not as a route (just like you're doing with `<FuncFact>`) and show it conditionally.

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <div className="App">
         <FuncFact />           
         <Route exact path="/" component = {Anime} />
         <Route exact path="/Controls"  component= {Controls} />
         <Route exact path="/Profile" component= {Profile} />
         <Route exact path="/People"   component = {People} />
         <ChatApp style={{display: this.state.showInbox ? 'block' : 'none'}} />
    </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Then set the `showInbox` state property to `true` using `this.setState()` when the user performs the action that should cause the `<ChatApp>` component to be shown. You may need to pass the action up through your components or use a state container like Redux.

Comment: Thank You very much Sir